# Is there way to check if given SQL was executed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, active-relation

I was wondering, is there easy way how to check if a given SQL was executed in current request?

let say I have

```
class Candy < ActiveRecord::Base

  def yummiest_candies
    @yummiest_candies = where(yummy: true, user_id: 1)
  end

  def do_something
    if was_executed?(yummiest_condies.to_sql)
      'do something'
    end
  end

  def was_executed? 
    # any ideas ??
  end
end
```

Obviously I can check logs, but I was wondering if there is a built in solution for this.

Also I could check if instance variable `@yummiest_candies` exist but was wondering if there is solution for checking SQL

**Question 2:** 
do you think code below would be worth doing? (in much complicated scenarios maybe)

```
  # app/model/candy.rb
  #...
  def factory_ids
    if was_executed?(yummiest_candies.to_sql)
      yummiest_candies.collect(&:factory_id)
    else
      yummiest_candies.pluck(:factory_id)
    end
  end
  #...
```

Thank you